# JQuery: How to make a JQuery plugin from a simple function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, placeholder

I have made this simple function that add placeholders to browsers that do not support them by default, like Explorer 8.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/avIfuDAf/2)

The question is: How can i make a plugin with that function? 
In order to remove the code from the html file and put it in a separate js file?

Thank you!

Comment: you do know there is already a [plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) for that?

Comment: Yes, but it is not only a specific question, it is also a general one, i would like to understand how to create JQuery plugin since i am quite new in JQuery. So if someone can help doing this i can learn also in general how to proceed, and it can be maybe useful to someone else that want to know how to make a JQuery plugin starting from a simple function.

Comment: ack. understood. see my answer below for a nice starting point for jQuery plugin basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so you know: there is already a [plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) for that.

JQuery UI has a nice [learning center](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).

Basic example from learning center above:

```
(function ( $ ) {

    var shade = "#556b2f";

    $.fn.placeholder = function() {
        // your code
        return this;
    };

}( jQuery ));
```